# Orchestras in real environments (for artistic effect)

Tags: orchestration

I have a really neat idea for an interesting orchestra performance, which takes place in an outside setting. What would happen if you decided to actually place the players in different places across a landscape. Place the trumpets on a mountain, the violinists behind the audience, hidden in the forest somewhere, etc. Would this create the effect I am thinking? I think this is a really neat idea, and I hope that it is practically achievable.

Comment: "Would this create the effect I am thinking?" -- What effect are you thinking?

Comment: It would add atmosphere.

Comment: It seems like it would be difficult to balance the sound, and how would the players coordinate their parts with some of them on a mountain and others hidden in a forest?

Comment: First, to address the coordination issue: You could setup wireless microphones to keep everything together, and if things are too quiet, setup some very high quality amplifiers.

Latency is a bit trickier, you would have to sync each player such that their parts are heard in sync, but are out of sync. The violin section should start playing a bit early, this would require very skilled players of course.

Comment: How far apart are your musicians? I feel that anything more then tens of metres or is going to be the equivalent of listening to a recording via the amplification system. Except it'll sound like everyone is mildly drunk and/or rhythm impaired.

Comment: I think everyone is misunderstanding me a bit, I have the sync issue thought out already, I just want to know if there is anything else I may have missed.

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten that sound travels relatively slowly.  If you place musicians even a hundred feet apart, that's about a tenth of a second delay, which is easily heard.   Unless you are planning to have each section play separately, this is a major problem.  In any case, the point of having different instruments in an orchestra is to produce different sonorities and tonalities, not different source points.

If all you want is for music from different instruments to "pop up" at different times in different directions, then you could do what you're thinking of.  I fear that this sort of game has been done to death in the recording studio by any number of rock bands.  It's amusing the first time you listen via headphones; after that it's just annoying.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a group named Urban Sax who were sax players, all wearing nuclear fall-out suits and radio-linked by belt pack to a central click. They were able to start playing widely separated, and converge on the central audience, and provided they could hear the click their playing would be in time. And they looked quite dramatic...

And don't forget the famous (notorious?) Stockhausen piece that features a string quartet, where each player is in their own helicopter.

Both these ensembles required the solution of some considerable technical difficulties. So it absolutely is possible to separate your musicians and provided they have an audible click or visual cue (CCTV of the conductor, maybe) then they'll be able to play in sync.  It'll be dramatic but does seem a bit gimmicky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen orchestra performances in concert halls with just the right amount of reverberation that were incredible. and I've seen the same performances outdoors that lacked any reverberation at all, that seemed to lack presence and power. Add the delays in sound from different distances reaching the listeners ears at different times and the experience would be confusing and probably  unpleasant.
However, I don't wish to dash your creativity, so I recommend trial and error until you are able to decide for yourself if this is a feasible idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a four-choir variant of "Erhalt uns Herr bei Deinem Wort" by Michael Prætorius where obviously you'd spread out the four choirs across your church.  I've performed in it, and it required heeding the conductor in the middle of the church well because you could not really go by sound at those distances.

Outside, this would be even trickier.  You are not going to properly hear trumpets from a mountain, either, unless you are talking about transmitting the sound and reproducing via a PA, and that seems sort of pointless.  Also, different acoustics for different instrument sources don't blend into a coherent auditory sensation for the listener: when stuff like "trumpets from mountain top" are integrated into a recording, they usually get a passage of their own separate from other instruments.

And the reason is not that the sound engineers are lacking "really neat ideas".

Comment: Amplifying it from the player's positions and firing at the audience, i meant.